# Comparing sencha touch 2.3.0 with 2.2.1

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I build my application using sencha command 3.1.2 using sencha lib 2.2.1. Now i like to update the my application to 2.3.1. I like to know what are the advancements are made is 2.3.1. Sencha documentation is not clear. There is any performance up-gradation in 2.3 not in UI? If there is any improvement in 2.3 so i will revert my app to latest version. Any suggestion techies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest change is PhoneGap direct support. There are also a lot of bug fixes, but regarding the performance, I personally feel there's no big difference.

Please read the release notes for detailed information: http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1/release-notes.html

Hope this helps.